# Can I register xsd with namespace then validate xml ignoring namespace

Tags: xml, namespaces, xsd

The XSD's that we register (which does not contain namespaces) are obtained from an identical XSD that contains a namespace (by deleting the namespace)
The XSD's with namespaces are required since its used in WSDL files.
This leads duplication of XSD's i.e we need to maintain 2 sets of XSD's (one with and one without namespace).

Will Oracle allow us to register an XSD that has a namespace with the command (register schema command) and then validate instance XML by ignoring the namespace?

XSD without namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!-- Element Declarations -->
            <xs:element name="S_NO" type="S_NOType">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:documentation>S_Number</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
```

XSD with namespace:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns="http://*****_request.*****.ws.*****.com"
     targetNamespace="http://*****_request.*****.ws.*****.com">
<!-- Element Declarations -->
            <xs:element name="S_NO" type="S_NOType">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>S_Number</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Usually such maneuvers are a sign that a team does not appreciate or
   understand namespaces.  My first recommendation would be that you
   take a broader perspective and consider **embracing namespaces
   consistently throughout your systems**.  Only if properly using namespaces
   is truly impossible in your situation would I move on to options #2 or #3...
2. Assuming your tool is
   Xerces-J-based, there's a [**namespace feature**](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/features.html#namespaces) that can be set to
   `false` that will disable processing of namespaces:
   **`http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces`**.  You may find that this
   does not work the way you're hoping it will with regard to
   validation, however.
3. You could bake into your build a simple **XSLT transformation** such
   that the namespace-less version of the XSD is derived automatically
   from the master, namespace-based XSD.

Comment: I think I will be resorting to the third option which will better suit our needs thanks for this answer